# Read Multiple JPG images using VTK

Tags: c++, vtk

I want to read multiple images (frames)  and  visualize them in a virtual environment with a certain delay  for that, I used this program    https://vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Images/InteractWithImage by as of now i create two images and visualizing with certain delay how to read multiple jpg files to use more frames

Comment: You are going to have to explain your problem in greater detail. I am having trouble finding your question.

Comment: Hi I am using VTK, C++ for visualizing images in the virtual environment and want to visualize multiple images with a certain delay to show it as video now I can visualize two images with certain delay continuously in the same way  I want to read series of images in a folder.